# No module named 'selenium.webdriver'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pip, virtualenv

I am trying to run some tests with selenium and firefox and I am getting the message "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium.webdriver'; 'selenium' is not a package"

I have tried all sorts of things after research but nothing is working. I figured using a virtual environment would be the easiest way but I cant get it going there either. Is there something I am missing? Any input is appreciated.

```
[jim@localhost Environments]$ ll ~/.local/bin/
total 8528
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jim jim     214 Sep  3 04:04 flask
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jim jim 8724590 Jan 28 17:49 geckodriver

[jim@localhost Environments]$ virtualenv -p python3.6 selenium
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.6
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/jim/Environments/selenium/bin/python3.6
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.

[jim@localhost Environments]$ source selenium/bin/activate

(selenium) [jim@localhost Environments]$ which python
~/Environments/selenium/bin/python

(selenium) [jim@localhost Environments]$ ~/Environments/selenium/bin/python --version
Python 3.6.4

(selenium) [jim@localhost Environments]$ pip install selenium
Collecting selenium 
(from selenium) (1.24.1)
Installing collected packages: selenium
Successfully installed selenium-3.141.0

(selenium) [jim@localhost Environments]$ pip freeze
selenium==3.141.0
urllib3==1.24.1

(selenium) [jim@localhost Environments]$ pip show selenium
Name: selenium
Version: 3.141.0
Summary: Python bindings for Selenium
Home-page: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/
Author: UNKNOWN
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/jim/Environments/selenium/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: urllib3
Required-by:

(selenium) [jim@localhost Environments]$ ~/Environments/selenium/bin/python
Python 3.6.4 (default, Dec 19 2017, 14:48:12)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jim/Environments/selenium.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium.webdriver'; 'selenium' is not 
a package
```

Comment: have you called your project `selenium`?!

Comment: Your virtual environment [folder] is named selenium and that will interfere. rename your virtual environment.

Comment: @MosheSlavin There is no project. I am just trying to run it from the command line.

Comment: @buran I built a new virtual environment named jim and it still happens.

Comment: @Jim, but did you also removed the old one? I would guess it's still there...

Answer (score 1):

As I have commented and so did @buran:

You have the python venv under a folder named `selenium` that mixes up the imports...

As you have shown `/home/jim/Environments/selenium/bin/python3.6` see the `bin` folder holding the python is named `selenium` change that and it should work fine!

You can change it to something like `new_selenium`: `/home/jim/Environments/new_selenium/bin/python3.6`

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Ah I see what you are saying. I removed the selenium virtual environment and now it works. Thanks guys.